# Fetch the products by attributes in magento from all the categories

Tags: magento, attributes

I am trying to fetch products from all categories. Actually I want to show a drop down list on homepage, from there attribute's value can be selected.

for example, 'vitamin a' or 'vitamin b'.

Now based on that selection all the product containing ingredient 'vitamin b' should be fetched.

I don't know how to do that? Please anyone can throw some light, I am trying to achieve this with one template file. But not getting the exact idea.

My attribute code is 'ingredient'. Based on that i want to fetch all the products from all the categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
/* @var $products Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */

$products->addAttributeToFilter('ingredient',{value});
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name'); // etc.

foreach ($products as $product) {
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    sprintf('%s<br />',$product->getName());
}
```

Comment: thank you @benmarks. Worked perfectly. Now I can have rich searching filters. :) :) Thanks again.